# What's the difference between returning inside a recursive function and having no return statement?

Tags: recursion

This code

```py
def ok():
    ok()
```

gives me a RecursionError, but this code

```py
def ok():
    return ok()
```

does not. Can someone explain why putting return there makes the function end, because even though I'm returning inside the first function, I'm still calling the same function again

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: I'm assuming this is python even though you haven't tagged it. Neither of your code variants contains a base case, so both are infinite recursions and both result in `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` on my machine. Your question is based on a faulty premise, since adding a `return` doesn't halt the function. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a function does not return a value, it depends on a side effect. This is true for *any* function.

```js
function stairs(n) {
  if (n > 0) {
    stairs(n - 1)
    console.log("*".repeat(n)) // print side effect
  }
}

stairs(5) // no returned value
```

When a function returns a value, the value can be used however the caller should decide -

```js
function stairs(n) {
  if (n > 0) {
    return stairs(n - 1) + "\n" + "*".repeat(n) // returned value
  }
  else {
    return "" // returned value
  }
}

console.log(stairs(5)) // print returned value from stairs
```